# How to decode JSON value that can be String or NSNumber?

Tags: swift

An API I am consuming sometimes returns:

`...
   total: "40"
...`

and sometimes:

`...
   total: 40
...`

Is there a clean way to write a guard/let statement that will extract an int value regardless of whether the parsed json object is an NSString or an NSNumber?

NOTE: I'm looking for the answer how to decode the value, not a reference to a library that allows me to punt on solving it. I already know about SwiftyJSON etc.

Comment: Yell at the developer who is producing the JSON to decide and be consistent.

Comment: both NSString & NSNumber respond to .integerValue, but I can't come up with the syntax for a guard-let that takes advantage of that, because it's not defined in a protocol.

Comment: hmmm, I suppose I could define a protocol myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I could define a protocol specifying the `integerValue` getter and empty protocol extensions to `NSString` and `NSNumber`, and then cast the value to that protocol:

```
protocol HasNumber {
  var integerValue: Int { get }
}
extension NSString:HasNumber{}
extension NSNumber:HasNumber{}
```

and then:

```
guard let total = (json["total"] as? HasNumber)?.integerValue else { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that you can call any method on `AnyObject`
via optional chaining. Example:

```
let jsonDict : [String : AnyObject] = ["foo" : 40, "bar" : "50" ]

if let val = jsonDict["foo"]?.integerValue 
{
    print(val) // 40
}

if let val = jsonDict["bar"]?.integerValue 
{
    print(val) // 50
}
```

If the value for the key does not exist, or does not respond
to `integerValue`, the result is `nil` and the optional binding
fails. Otherwise, the integer value is assigned to `val`.

Comment: this gets very cumbersome to DRY when you add in error handling. EDIT: actually not, I misread. I didn't realize you could do that. I should have tried it, I just assumed it wouldn't work.

Comment: I think I'll keep my protocol though, it makes things very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach

```
let jsonDict : [String : CustomStringConvertible] = ["foo" : 40, "bar" : "50" ]
for (_, value) in jsonDict {
  print(Int("\(value)")!)
}
```